# Loading and using a trained TensorFlow model in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a model in TensorFlow using the `tf.estimator` API, more specifically using `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`. I have the output directory of the training. How do I load my model from this and then use it?

I have tried using the `tf.train.Saver` class by loading the most recent `ckpt` file and restoring the session. However, then to call `sess.run()` I need to know what the name of the output node of the graph is so I can pass this to the `fetches` argument. What is the name/how can I access this output node? Is there a better way to load and use the trained model?

Note that I have already trained and saved the model in a `ckpt` file, so please do not suggest that I use the `simple_save` function.

Comment: can you send the ckpt file that you have saved. and is there a testing part in the code that you used to train. the names of nodes depend on what model you use. so if you can share the code maybe i can try to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `tf.train.list_variables('ckpt file')` to inspect all variables saved in your checkpoint file. And you can use `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint()` to warm start from your file. You can only use variables present in your checkpoint by using assigment map

```
 variables_from_ckpt = [i[0] for i in tf.train.list_variables('ckpt file')]  
 assigment_map = {variable.op.name: variable for variable in tf.global_variables() if variable.op.name in variables_from_ckpt}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question) I realized that the easiest way to do this was to use the `tf.estimator` API. By initializing an estimator that warm starts from the model directory, it's possible to just call `estimator.predict` and pass the correct args (`predict_fn`) and get the predictions immediately. It's not required to deal with the graph variables in any way.